# Case statements are not advancing to the next statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, ifstream

I am using switch statement to read from a text file using case statements and when the program is running, it is not advancing to the next case but stops at case 1. If I remove the break statement, the program will advance to the next case but will copy over the same information from case 1.

This is for a course project that I am working on for school so my knowledge is limited, I am just looking for help as to what is wrong and how to fix.

Different lines of code, added {} between each case to separate the variable.

```
void displayPlaylists(void)
{
    string input1;
    string line = "";
    line.assign(20, '-');
    ifstream playlistText(PlaylistNames);
    if (playlistText.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(playlistText, input1))
        {
            cout << "Current Playlist: " << endl;
            cout << input1 << '\n';
        }
        playlistText.close();
    }
    string input2, fieldBuffer;
    ifstream songText(SongNames);
    int fieldcount = 1;
    if (songText.is_open())
    {
        getline(songText, fieldBuffer, ',');
        while (getline(songText, input2))
        {
            cout << "Song list:\n";
            cout << line << endl;
            switch (fieldcount)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    cout << "Song Title: " << fieldBuffer << endl;
                }
                break;
                case 2:
                {
                    cout << "Song Artist: " << fieldBuffer << endl;
                }
                break;
                case 3:
                {
                    cout << "Genre: " << fieldBuffer << endl;
                }
                    break;
                case 4:
                {
                    cout << "Duration: " << fieldBuffer << endl;
                    fieldcount = 0;
                }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
                getline(songText, fieldBuffer, ',');
                // << input2 << '\n';
        }
        songText.close();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

The output should come out showing

### Song List:

Song title: --
Song artist: --
Song genre --
Song duration --

What I am getting

### Song List:

Song title: Riot

Press any key to continue...

Comment: If you’re always going to read four fields in the same order, you can do that by reading four times in sequence without counting.

Answer (score 1):

You never changed `fieldcount`, so its value is always 1, so the same case always runs.

Presumably you intended to progressively increment it as you traverse the lines of the input file.

Just removing the `break` is wrong — you're still operating on the same line from the file, and don't want to run *all* the cases for every line.

Review your [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) technique!

Comment: It makes sense but it does not at the same time. I think I am way over complicating it at this point since I have been staring at this for a few days now and looking at different lines of code to find my error. Could I trouble you for an example? Not from my code but something that will lead me in the direction I need to be in.

Comment: @MurrDur It is almost always easier to over-complicate. A good improvement though is to make a `Song` data structure and use it to gather up all of the song reading, writing, and other management functions with the song data. Then you can just have all 4 `getline`s in a row and a check of the input stream at the end. If the stream has failed, you didn't get all four and you didn't get a valid `Song`. Discard it and carry on with the ones that were good, or complain to the user.